# Web Browser for a site that with a single click install

Tags: browser

I would like to create a browser for my site that can be installed very easily. It should give the user the option to start with the computer, replace homepage links, etc. How can I do this....

The browser should be an executable which when loaded will show my website's homepage.

Thanks Guys

Comment: Why not simply providing them the http link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at prism (http://prism.mozillalabs.com/)

Comment: thanks tim...is there anything more custom maybe like an executable that be installed by other people.